# Compare date Range by Month (Integer) and Year (Integer)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, datetime, outsystems

I'm having a problem comparing the date range. I have to validate dates that are within a certain month and year. The month and year are integer values.

NOTE: I´m using OUTSYSTEMS aggregates using Oracle DataBase

Example for two results of a query:

```
    Start Date    End Date 
1   2020-08-16    2020-10-14
2   2019-11-01    2020-08-15
```

**Case 1**

Input:

```
Month = 9
Year = 2020
```

Expected Result:

```
    Start Date    End Date 
1   2020-08-16    2020-10-14
```

**Case 2**

Input:

```
Month = 8
Year = 2020
```

Expected Result:

```
    Start Date    End Date 
1   2020-08-16    2020-10-14
2   2019-11-01    2020-08-15
```

**Case 3**

Input:

```
Month = 3
Year = 2020
```

Expected Result:

```
    Start Date    End Date 
2   2019-11-01    2020-08-15
```

**Case 4**

Input:

```
Month = 10
Year = 2019
```

Expected Result: No Row

The selection is in Java Way. I´m using a system function like Month() and Year() to convert the rows to the integers.

Like this

```
((Month(StartDate) <= Month and Month(EndDate) = Month)
and
(Year(StartDate) <= Year and Year(EndDate) = Year))
or
((Month(StartDate) <= Month and Month(EndDate) = Month)
and
(Year(StartDate) <= Year and Year(EndDate) = Year))
```

The code above won't work. I try many combinations without success. I have no special comparison functions. For my analysis, I have four scenarios to create to bring the dates that are included in the month and year that I am researching. But I'm not getting the code to work. Someone can light the way for me

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, sql-server, postgresql...? Date functions are highly vendor-specific

Comment: Thanks. I´m using Outsystems Aggregates.

Comment: I don't think that Outsystems Aggregates is a database (based on the tag info at least). You would need to find out what the database behind the application is.

Comment: Ok. Is Oracle. But i need to use in aggregate (soo i refer the sintax bove). Thanks

Comment: Oracle has no `year()` and `month()` function - so in that database, your existing code would raise a compilation error.

Comment: Like i say above. I´m using Aggregates (Outsystems Accelerators), in this way i´m just able to use synthase like I mentioned above. Just using fields and using basic operators like < > >= or <= AND and OR

Comment: Outsystems has its own aggregates with specific syntax. The platform then converts them to Oracle or SQL queries in compile time so that the developer doesn't have to worry about that. So in this scope, it does not matter what is the database engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach uses arithmetics:

```
where year * 100 + month 
    between year(startdate) * 100 + month(startdate)
        and year(enddate)   * 100 + month(enddate)
```

However this probably isn't the most efficient method. In general, you want to avoid applying functions on the column you filter on. A better alternative woul be to convert the year/month parameter to a date - unfortunately you did not tag your database, and date functions are highly vendor-specific, so it is not really possible to suggest.

If you don't want `between`:

```
where year * 100 + month >= year(startdate) * 100 + month(startdate)
  and year * 100 + month <= year(enddate)   * 100 + month(enddate)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. Two reasons. I am limited to the syntax I presented (so I cannot use 'between' or 'where'). Second, I can't convert it to date because I would have to set a day. And in this case, the day is irrelevant and could affect the search. In case 2 that I related, I want the queries to give me two results

Comment: @PedroEstevesAntunes: you can easily turn `between` to two inequalities conditions. See my update.

Comment: I´m just able to use the syntax above. Just using fields and using basic operators like < > >= or <= AND and OR. Thanks

Comment: @PedroEstevesAntunes: what do you mean? You can use `year(startdate)` but not `year(startdate) * 100 + month(startdate)`?

Comment: Sorry GMB. It works like a charm. Now I can filter by date. I need to analyze your filter better to see if I understand. It feels strange to me. But it works perfectly. Crazy stuff :)

Comment: @PedroEstevesAntunes: welcome. The logic is to turn both input and dates to a format like YYYYMM, as an integer value. We can then do simple comparisons.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222350/discussion-between-pedroestevesantunes-and-gmb).

Comment: The logic will serve for more scenarios. Thank you very much. Thumbs ups  :)

Comment: I’d find it more natural to multiply by 12. But any number that is at least 12 works (as long as the calculation doesn’t overflow).

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? Considering your inputs **m** for month and **y** for year:

```
StartDate <= AddDays(AddMonths(NewDate(Year(y), Month(m), 1),1)-1)
and
EndDate >= NewDate(Year(y), Month(m), 1))
```

The thinking is like: filter by all start dates that are lower than the last day of input month and all the end dates that are greater than the first day of input month.

Regarding performance, with this approach you don't have to do any logic/filter on the columns you're filtering on.

Comment: Hello @pipo.The GMB solution worked well. The question of filtering by day I don't know if it will work. Because I can have two or more dates to finish and start in the same month. I think that filtering by day here would ruin this research.

Comment: I believe that case is covered by this solution. But nothing better than a simple test to check it out

Answer (score 1):

### The vendor-independent solution

The answer by GMB is nice, I might go with it if it were me. As GMB says, it is vendor specific because the date functions are. If you want a solution that works across database vendors, do the date math in Java so you only need simple date comparisons in the database.

```
    int month = 8;
    int year = 2020;

    YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of(year, month);
    LocalDate monthStart = ym.atDay(1);
    LocalDate monthEnd = ym.atEndOfMonth();
```

When you pass these dates to your query, your search condition may be put simply:

```
  where startDate <= monthEnd and endDate >= monthStart
```